# SQL Server stored procedure for randomly assigning survey

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have to do the following: Select instructors from an existing table, randomly assign them 1 of 4 surveys and enter the instructors and the assigned survey into an existing table (teacherID, surveyID), and finally randomly select 5 of their students and record this into another existing table (studentID and teacherID).

As separate tasks this would be easy...err, easier.

Not having done this before I am trying to figure out the best process. Create a temp table to first store the teachers and then somehow loop (I've never done this in a stored procedure) through that to randomly assign surveys and then insert into the survey table? Create another temp table for randomly selecting the teacher's students then assign that into the survey students table?

In response to rsbarro's question below: There are three tables. One records the name of the survey and has an auto incremented id field. Another has the teacherID and the assigned surveyID. The last one has the studentID, TeacherID and the remaining columns are for recording the responses (Q1, Q2, Q3, etc). The survey ID is not recorded in the teacher-student table.  This web app was previously done by importing data from either an Excel file or Access database that used a macro for assigning the surveys and students.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Does the "other" existing table have a surveyID column as well? Without it you won't be able to tell which students are assigned to which teacher for which survey. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming at least SQL Server 2005:

```
/* Assign 1 random survey to each teacher */
INSERT INTO TeacherSurvey
    (teacherID, surveyID)
    SELECT teacherID, (SELECT TOP 1 surveyID FROM Survey ORDER BY NEWID())
        FROM Teacher

/* Randomly choose 5 students for each teacher */
INSERT INTO TeacherStudentSurvey
    (teacherID, studentID)
    SELECT teacherID, studentID
        FROM (SELECT teacherID, studentID,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY teacherID ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RowNum
                  FROM TeacherStudent) t
        WHERE t.RowNum <= 5
```

Comment: So I was just told that the survey is assigned in sequential order (1,2,3,4). How would that change the code? Thanks, james

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what you want with the students so here is some code that takes care of the first part. Randomly assigning a survey to a teacher. Maybe you can use this to figure out how you should solve what is left.

```
-- Table with instructors
declare @Teacher table(TeacherID int, Name varchar(15))
insert into @Teacher values (1, 'Instructor 1')
insert into @Teacher values (2, 'Instructor 2')
insert into @Teacher values (3, 'Instructor 3')
insert into @Teacher values (4, 'Instructor 4')
insert into @Teacher values (5, 'Instructor 5')

-- Table with the four surveys
declare @Survey table(SurveyID int, SurveyName varchar(15))
insert into @Survey values (1, 'Survey 1')
insert into @Survey values (2, 'Survey 2')
insert into @Survey values (3, 'Survey 3')
insert into @Survey values (4, 'Survey 4')

-- Target table for Teacher and randomly selected Survey
declare @TeacherSurvey table(TeacherID int, SurveyID int)

insert into @TeacherSurvey (TeacherID, SurveyID)
select 
  T.TeacherID,
  (select top 1 SurveyID
   from @Survey 
   order by newid()) as SurveyID
from @Teacher as T
```

Rows in @TeacherSurvey

```
TeacherID   SurveyID
----------- -----------
1           2
2           2
3           4
4           4
5           3
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. What I was told, the survey has to do with students enrollment in a program. I believe the survey has to do with students performance and how the program is benefiting them.